# Conservative/Non-conservative nature of hinge force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rigid-body-dynamics

Can total mechanical energy be conserved for a hinged rod free to move in the $X-Y$ plane? Because, there's the hinge force. If it is non-conservative, energy won't be conserved. Is it conservative?
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the set up? It's not entirely clear what you're really aiming to ask.

Comment: If the rod lies in a conservative field, then the energy _is_ conserved, why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Because there's the hinge force. If it is non-conservative, energy won't be conserved.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your system properly. In any case, if the hinge force does not do work it must be conservative.

Comment: @Diracology Conservativeness depends on presence of a non-conservative force or whether work is done by the non-conservative force?

Comment: @Anubhad Das - A force is called conservative if its work does not depend on the path. As a result the work of a conservative force on a closed path is zero. Since the hinge force does not do work, it satisfies the definition of a conservative force. Of course your system is a rigid body and not a particle, but the idea is the same.